# Upload image to different domain on same server

Tags: php, apache2, lamp, symlink

Using a standard LAMP server with full control, I need to upload an image from DomianA using a PHP script to a directory on DomainB.  The server has suPHP and mod_security in place.

Currently using an absolute path to DomainB I am getting the error:

`Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: open_basedir restriction in effect.`

I tried to `chown` the upload directory on DomainB to the user of DomainA (where the script is being run). With no luck.

After researching I have found two potential solutions, and want to see if there are any better methods.  And maybe some code to get me going in the right direction.

1. Symlink - so basically have a dir (below the domain level I guess?) then have each domain have a symbolic link to that location.
2. Modify my httpd.conf - not sure what to do, but I don't want to open any potential security holes by doing this.

Comment: If you don't get sufficient help here, you may look @ serverfault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If domain B only needs to serve up files from that directory and not modify them, then put the directory somewhere in domain A's tree, with proper permissions to allow the uploads.

You can then configure domain B to access that directory via an alias:

```
Alias /path/to/the/files/in/domain/A  /dom_a_dir
```

Then you can access the files directly via

```
http://dom.b.com/dom_a_dir
```

Comment: huh, looks elegant :) - what happens if the user right clicks the image to view full image, will the full URL be the actual location on domainA?  Or does the Alias take care of that?

Comment: An Apache Alias directive is basically like a symlink, except it exists only at the Apache level, rather than on the file system.

Comment: thanks.  Just to make sure, I should be setting up the Alias in my httpd.conf, right?

Comment: Put it where you can find it later. Personally, I'd put it in the .conf file that sets up the domainB website, just to keep everything directly related to that site in one place.